# Вызов метода объекта по ссылке родительского класса в C#

Tags: c#, наследование

Всем привет! У меня имеется код на C#, в котором объявлены класс `Point` и его производные, в том числе класс `RightTriangle:Point`. Я создал ссылку, которую необходимо при определённых условиях приравнивать к разным классам (все они произведены от `Point`), и по этой ссылке нужно вызывать методы (простые Get/Set) и также проводить сравнение (`Equals`, `GetHashCode`, `==`, `!=` переопределены для каждого производного класса). Проблема в том, что это банально не работает. Среда пишет, что никаких методов дочерних классов по этой ссылке нет, сравнение, очевидно, тоже не проходит, выдавая `false` на все случаи.

```
Point obj1;
obj1 = rtr1; // rtr1 имеет класс RightTriangle:Point
obj1.GetSideA(); // не работает, но у RightTriangle есть метод GetSideA

RightTriangle obj2;
obj2 = rtr1;
obj2.GetSideA(); // теперь работает, но я не знаю класс obj2 заранее
```

upd: почитал MSDN, по своей проблеме ничего не нашёл. Пока что реализовал алгоритм с помощью тонны отвратительных конструкций на `if`-ах, но очень бы не хотелось так оставлять, потому что смысл всего ООП в моей работе тогда вообще теряется.

Comment: Какой вы ожидаете результат, если вы вызываете метод класса `RightTriangle`, а объект на самом деле не будет класса `RightTriangle` (а всего лишь `Point`)?

Comment: Ну и по смыслу ООП. наследовать треугольник от точки как-то не кажется хорошей идеей. Треугольник **не является** точкой.

Comment: А в классе Point :) есть функция GetSideA()? По-моему вы хотите реализовать полиморфизм, только как то через задний проход.

Comment: @VladD я понимаю, но  с преподавателем не поспоришь.

Comment: @Mirdin Спасибо огромное! Нужно было создать виртуальный метод в Point, а затем перезаписать его в RightTriangle.

Comment: Что должен вернуть метод GetSideA у треугольника? Что будет, если вызвать этот же метод у точки и у линии например?

Comment: @Monk Должен вернуть поле `sideA` у `RightTriangle`. Но, как я уже написал, я не понял, что нужно было создать этот же метод для родительского класса.

Comment: Вы сделали работающее решение, но неправильное. У точки НЕ ДОЛЖНО быть метода, который она даже в теории неспособна реализовать. Я даже не уверен, как должен выглядеть такой код, потому что вопрос задан слишком узко. По возможности - опишите, зачем вы пытаетесь вызывать всё из объекта с типом базового класса(точка).

Comment: Ну во-первых, не наследуйте от точки. Наследование - это отношение This is... А фигура относится с точкой как Has is..., то есть мы имеем композицию. Во-вторых сделайте абстрактный класс Figure и наследуйте уже от него. Иначе, преподаватель над вами сильно поиздевается.

Comment: 2Monk Вызывать всё по одной ссылке желательно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, скажем, "изменить радиус", мне не приходилось проверять, какая радио-кнопка нажата (окружности или конуса), а просто мог нааписать в одну строку `t1.SetRadius();`. В свою очередь, в обработчике клика кнопки "окружность" написать `t1 = circle1;`.

Comment: «С преподавателем не поспоришь» — плохая позиция. С преподавателями можно и нужно аргументированно спорить.

Comment: @Urffly вам НУЖНО проверять, какая радиокнопка нажата, окружность или косинус, потому что радиус окружности и конуса не взаимосвязаны напрямую для реализации этого изменения через методы\свойства. Конус не является наследником окружности, они в разномерных пространствах расположены. Как раз таки для облегчения подобной фигни придуманы интерфейсы. В данном случае - это какой то интерфейс `IHasRadius`. Его будут реализовывать все, кому надо, а вы после клика на форме сможете приводить объект к интерфейсу и работать с радиусом. UPD: по крайней мере, в шарпе нет множественного наследования.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Point
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
      var p2 = obj as Point;
      return p2 != null && p2.X == X && p2.Y == Y;
    }
}
class Circle: Point
{
    public int R;
    override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
      var c2 = obj as Circle;
      return c2 != null && c2.X == X && c2.Y == Y && c2.R == R;
    }
}
class Triangle: Point
{
    public int X2;
    public int Y2;
    public int X3;
    public int Y3;
    override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
      var t2 = obj as Triangle;
      return t2 != null && t2.X == X && t2.Y == Y 
                        && t2.X2 == X2 && t2.Y2 == Y2 
                        && t2.X3 == X3 && t2.Y3 == Y3;
    }
}


Point p = new Circle();

var circle = p as Circle;
if (circle != null)
  circle.R = 10;
```

Comment: А треугольник из точки как выразить? =) Я вот залип что-то на этом странном требовании.

Comment: @Monk добавил треугольник

Comment: Хм, интересная реализация. Технически оно вроде и похоже на правду, только вот логика получается странная.

Comment: @Monk Обучающая начальная задача. Логики - минимум: на выделение общего между типами и записывании этого в виде кода.

Comment: Судя по тому, что автор пишет в комментариях - не особо это он решить пытается.